# ¿Como hacer un datatable que tenga una seleccion por defecto?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

tengo una pequeña duda, no se como hacer que un datatable con un selectionmode="multiple", me traiga un elemento ya seleccionado, es decir, que al ingresar al modulo, ya este seleccionado en la datatable el elemento que deseo.
este el codigo del datatable:

```html
 <p:dataTable id="dt_proyectos_new"
                                     value="#{usuarioBean.allProyectos}"
                                     style="text-align: center; font-size: 10px;text-transform: capitalize;"
                                     rowKey="#{proyectoselect.proyectoId}"
                                     selection="#{usuarioBean.proyectosSelected}"
                                     tableStyle="width:auto"
                                     paginator="false"
                                     emptyMessage="No se encontraron proyectos"
                                     var="proyectoselect" 
                                     rowSelectMode="checkbox">                      
                            <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px;text-align:center" />
                            <p:column headerText="Nombre" filterBy="#{proyectoselect.proyectoId}" 
                                      filterStyle="display:none"
                                      width="80%">
                                <h:outputText value="#{proyectoselect.proyectoNombre}" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="Codigo EPS" width="20%">
                                <h:outputText value="#{proyectoselect.proyectoCodeeps}"/>                                
                            </p:column>
                        </p:dataTable>
```

agradezco pronta respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Usa este atributo en el tag del datatable `filteredValue="{ListaValores.onFilterChange}">`

Donde el ValorFiltrado es tu evento dentro del managedBean que devuelve los filtros que necesitas

```
@Named(value = "ListaValores")
@SessionScoped
public class Lista implements Serializable{
      private Map<String, String> estadoFiltro = new HashMap<String, String>();
      private List<Ciudad> valorFiltro;

      public Lista() {
      }

      public void onFilterChange(FilterEvent filterEvent) {
         estadoFiltro = filterEvent.getFilters();
         valorFiltro =(List<Ciudad>) filterEvent.getData();
      }

      public String estadoFiltro(String column) {
         return estadoFiltro.get(column);
      }

      public List<Ciudad> getValorFiltro() {
         return valorFiltro;
      }

      public void setValorFiltro(List<Ciudad> valorFiltro) {
         this.valorFiltro = valorFiltro;
      }
}
```